# iOS Inter-class Block Signaling

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, block

I've read up on blocks as much as I can, however I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept. I've used blocks regularly where they are utilized to call success and failure blocks in an object's owner's class.

So, say I have `ClassA` with a variable of `ClassB`. I call `[ClassB method1]`. What exactly must be put into `method1` in order to add the ability to run a success block assuming all goes well within `method1`? How does it know to invoke the success block that is written into `ClassA`? Any examples would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough and quick example.

In ClassB.h define the function with a success / failure block:

```
- (void)doSomethingOnSuccess:(void (^)(NSString *resultString))success
                     failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

In ClassB.m:

```
- (void)doSomethingOnSuccess:(void (^)(NSString *resultString))success
                     failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
{
  // Do some task
  BOOL taskSucceed = [self doSomeTask];
  if (taskSucceed) {
    NSString *result = @"done";
    // Check for success block
    if (success) 
      success(result);
  } else {
    // Generate error
    NSError *error = ...;
    if (failure)
      failure(error);
  }

}
```

Finally, in ClassA:

```
[ClassB doSomethingOnSuccess:^(NSString *resultString) {
  // method succeeded
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
  // something failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think of a block as a block of code that you can store and execute whenever you like. So your classes could look like:

`ClassA.m`

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    ClassB *obj = [ClassB new];
    [obj doSomethingAndThen:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"WIN!");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Oh no");
        }
    }
}
```

---

`ClassB.h`

```
typedef void (^SuccessBlock)(BOOL success);

@interface ClassB : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) SuccessBlock successBlock;

- (void)doSomethingAndThen:(SuccessBlock)block;

@end
```

---

`ClassB.m`

```
@interface ClassB

- (void)doSomethingAndThen:(SuccessBlock)block
{
    self.successBlock = block;

    // Assume LRThing is something like NSURLConnection
    LRThing *thing = [LRThing new];
    thing.delegate = self;
    [thing start];
}

- (void)longRunnigThingDidEnd
{
    if (_successBlock) {
        _successBlock(YES);
        self.successBlock = nil;
    }
}

- (void)longRunningThingDidFail
{
    if (_successBlock) {
        _successBlock(NO);
        self.successBlock = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

That's a very simple example, and obviously you want to do more checks, e.g. checking whether you already have a block before assigning one to `self.successBlock`. Hope this helps!